# Consolidate, merge and sum values in vba

Tags: vba, excel, consolidation

I have a table which has duplicates of the same person and I'm wanting to merge these down into a single row whilst summing up two columns assigned to each row of data.

For example:
[image]

I am wanting to merge the data in columns A to D by using column A as my 'reference point' on what to match. I then want the values to be added together in Columns E and F. Giving me the results below.

[image]

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this but I'm pretty new to VBA and haven't come across anything.

Thanks

Comment: [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576) to the rescue!

Comment: I want this to be done automatically as part of a process and so want to do it with VBA.

Comment: So record yourself building a pivot table and you'll have a vba solution

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using the following code:

```
Sub foo()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To LastRow
    Sheet1.Cells(x, 7).Value = "=SUMIF(R1C1:R17C6,RC[-6],C[-2])"
    Sheet1.Cells(x, 8).Value = "=SUMIF(R1C1:R17C6,RC[-7],C[-2])"
Next x

Range("G2:H" & LastRow).Copy
Range("G2:H" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("E2:F" & LastRow).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$H$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

In essence, the code sums all the values in column G & H then copies and paste as values (to get rid of the formulas on the cells) then deletes the contents from columns E & F, shifting to the left to bring the new values to the right columns, and finally it removes any duplicates to give you the compiled list as you wanted.